# IEEEtran: IEEEParstart overlapping letters

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, line-spacing, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'm creating a `IEEEtran` document, I noted that if I use:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\IEEEPARstart{?`}{Qu\'e} es lo que es tan inusual en la microelectr\'onica?. La respuesta es
que es uno de esas raras tecnolog\'ias en las que la ciencia precedi\'o al arte y la ingenier
\'ia. La ciencia, en este caso es una contribuci\'on de notables como Wilson, Schottky, Pauli
Fermi, Dirac y Davydov, por nombrar s\'olo unos pocos. Para la mayor\'ia de las otras tecnolo
g\'ias, por el contrario, la secuencia es al rev\'es.
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: IEEEParstarResult]

How can I prevent the inverted question mark from overlapping the 3rd text line?. Is there a way to change the IEEEParstart letters size (to simplify the procedure)?

Comment: The command assumes (wrongly), that the initial has no depth, that is, it doesn't descend under the baseline, which is normal for capital letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command assumes that all initials will be without descenders and doesn't offer an interface for changing the parameters.

However, one can act on `\@IEEEPARstartDROPDEPTH`, which usually means `1.1\baselineskip`, for decreasing the font size of the dropped capital and correct the problem. Here is a change to the standard command, accepting an optional argument for setting the factor.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\let\origIEEEPARstart\IEEEPARstart
\renewcommand{\IEEEPARstart}[3][1.1]{%
  \def\@IEEEPARstartDROPDEPTH{#1\baselineskip}%
  \origIEEEPARstart{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\IEEEPARstart{A}{bc} blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\IEEEPARstart[0.7]{?`}{Qu\'e} es lo que es tan inusual en la microelectr\'onica?. La respuesta es
que es uno de esas raras tecnolog\'ias en las que la ciencia precedi\'o al arte y la ingenier
\'ia. La ciencia, en este caso es una contribuci\'on de notables como Wilson, Schottky, Pauli
Fermi, Dirac y Davydov, por nombrar s\'olo unos pocos. Para la mayor\'ia de las otras tecnolo
g\'ias, por el contrario, la secuencia es al rev\'es.

\IEEEPARstart{A}{bc} blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]